# Adding javadoc to a library included as .jar in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, javadoc

I'm using [Twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) for a Twitter Java client Java FX App. I downloaded the sources and included the `.jar` to NetBeans after going to: `Projects->Libraries->Add Jar/Folder`.

I'd like to include the JavaDoc for library but at site they only offer an [html](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/index.html).

I've tried:

- downloading the html and adding the folder as JavaDoc for that jar,
- downloading and compressing to index.html and the downloaded folder to `.jar`
- adding the URL

But got any good results. .

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried using `Add URL...` and pasting `http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/index.html` into it?

Comment: I tried, and got nto results

Comment: What do you mean by "adding javadoc"? Have javadoc available in your IDE, enable Javadoc links in your code?

Comment: @fge I mean having javadoc available in IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Maven Central, you *can* have the javadoc jar.

When listing the [available files for version 2.1.4](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/twitter4j/twitter4j-core/2.1.4/) there is a:

```
twitter4j-core-2.1.4-javadoc.jar
```

Netbeans should be able to download maven dependencies, including javadoc; at least, IDEA does.